# Issues getting images from a folder and using a path for href and image source

Tags: php, arrays, readdir

I'm new to PHP and having some troubles.
I need to get some images to display as:

```
<a rel="example_group" href="slidesstartpagina/DESOMVIELE-Bloemen-01.jpg"     title="Desomviele bloemen en decoraties"><img src="slidesstartpagina/DESOMVIELE-Bloemen-01-tn.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

The PHP code I wrote does display the first path perfectly for the `<a href>`, but for the `<img src>` it files with `Array` instead of using the filename.
I must be doing something wrong using of that array.

Any Idea?

My code:

```
<?php
$paththumb = "img/bloemen_thumb/";
$pathimg = "img/bloemen_img/";
$images = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($pathimg));
$thumbs = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($paththumb));
$i=1;
foreach ($thumbs as $block) {
if ($i%16 == 1)
{  
echo '<div class="block2 gallery">';
}
if ($thumbs[0] == '.');
foreach ($images as $value) {echo '<a rel="example_group"        href="img/bloemen_img/'.$value.'" title="Desomviele bloemen en decoraties"><img src="img/bloemen_thumb/'.$thumbs.'" alt="" /></a>';
};
if ($i%4 == 0)
{
    echo '</div>';
};
 $i++;
if ($i%16 != 1) echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You are echoing `$thumbs` which is an array here: `<img src="img/bloemen_thumb/'.$thumbs.'" alt="" />`

Comment: use $block instead of $thumbs in your img tag.

Comment: Thank you, that just did the trick. Any Idea what I do wrong with deciding? I want a div around every 16 images. But it puts the same image in the div the first time and al the other images go without a Div around it.

Comment: @user3799112: If you have a new question, please ask it ask a new question, rather than appending it to this one. Also, take note of the formatting improvements made to your post, and try to apply the same in any further questions you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put those div's inside "foreach" loop.
If filenames are the same for thimbs and images you can use one loop:

```
$paththumb = 'img/bloemen_thumb/';
$pathimg = 'img/bloemen_img/';
$thumbs = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($paththumb));
$i=1;

echo '<div class="block2 gallery">';
foreach ($images as $key => $value) {

    echo '<a rel="example_group" href="img/bloemen_img/'.$images[$key].'" title="Desomviele bloemen en decoraties"><img src="img/bloemen_thumb/'.$thumbs[$key].'" alt="" /></a>';

    if($i%16==0){echo '</div><div class="block2 gallery">';}
    $i++;   
}
echo '</div>';
```

Would be also great to check if file exists...

Comment: could you post me how it should look like for you?

Comment: thanks again, but the filenames differ. The problem is I wanted to put a div around every 16th image. In your solution it will put all images in one div. The check for existing files is a great idea

Comment: This really did it. To bad I don't have the reputation yet to vote this up. Thx

Comment: ow, one little problem. It does load the thumbs instead of the images in the href now

Comment: http://www.bloemen-desomviele.be/desomvielebloemen.php is the url. When i click the thumb it gives an error now

Comment: You have to loop over both arrays like this for example: 

`foreach ($images as $key => $value){

  echo " $images[$key] $thumbs[$key]";


}`

But only if those two arrays are same length